# Kernel Log "TCP: Treason uncloaked!"

Tags: linux, networking, hardware, kernel

On one linux server (Gentoo hardened), we are experiencing bursts of the following messages in dmesg from time to time:

```
TCP: Treason uncloaked! Peer xx.xx.xxx.xxx:65039/80 shrinks window 4094157295:4094160199. Repaired.
```

Is there anything we should take care of or is this normal?

**Update:** Maybe related, we are using `net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = cubic`. Kernel version is 2.6.28 with Gentoo hardening patches.

**Update:** This could probably really be related to hardware/driver issues, as we are seeing a "hickup" on the switches sometimes: The port goes down and comes up again. Only lately we discovered the following dmesg output related to these port hickups:

```
[5781269.910133] e1000: eth0: e1000_clean_tx_irq: Detected Tx Unit Hang
[5781269.910136]   Tx Queue             <0>
[5781269.910137]   TDH                  <e0>
[5781269.910139]   TDT                  <76>
[5781269.910140]   next_to_use          <76>
[5781269.910141]   next_to_clean        <da>
[5781269.910143] buffer_info[next_to_clean]
[5781269.910144]   time_stamp           <22750e54>
[5781269.910146]   next_to_watch        <e2>
[5781269.910147]   jiffies              <22750f5f>
[5781269.910148]   next_to_watch.status <0>
```

Usually after these logged lines there also follow some "Treason uncloaked" lines (but not vice versa, means these are not always logged before "Treason uncloaked").

Comment: Don't you think that title is a bit over the top? Perhaps you should look up the definition of treason.

Comment: @John That's just copy and pasted from the kernel log message... So is the log message over the top?

Comment: Yes. (stupid 15 character minimum)

Comment: @John Better now?

Comment: Yep :) (still 15 character limit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this message when people decide to "optimize" TCP parmameters on remote systems, but it could be a syn flood attack as well.

There were a few known Kernel bugs that caused this message to be appear in error. I believe they were fixed in the 2.6.26 kernel.

Comment: May it be related to using the cubic congestion control algorithm? May the error be yielded less/more when using other congestion controls?

Comment: This exact log message has been removed from the kernel a long time ago, it should no longer occur. I believe your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

The reson may be any of the following:

1. Bad tcpstack parameters
2. Remote attack
3. Bugs in the kernel or network adapter driver ( I had these in the past with Intel EtherExpress PRO/100 and eepro100 driver )
4. Faulty network adapter
5. Damaged or bad cables

Comment: How to debug if the network adapter driver is the culprit? We are using the gigabit adapter by Intel (e1000).

Comment: you can try to find alternative driver for that adapter or just install another adapter, connect everything to it and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

What version of Linux are you using? It could be [a bug in your kernel](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=2ad41065d9fe518759b695fc2640cf9c07261dd2).

Comment: It's kernel 2.6.28... I've updated the question to reflect this.