# What is the meaning of "Treason Uncloaked" in Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, tcp

On a Linux Apache server, from time to time, there are messages saying `TCP: Treason uncloaked!`.

There are [previous questions on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/123010/kernel-log-tcp-treason-uncloaked) explaining the fixes for this issue.

However does anyone know the meaning of this error message? Why would mis-matched TCP messages provoke such an unclear error message? Has this message got some history behind it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [part of a long tradition](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Mailing-Lists/Kernel/2008-12/msg07082.html) of attempts (and successes) at humor in Unix and Linux error messages. It simply means that a TCP window was shrunk unexpectedly.

Comment: As traditions go it's more annoying than useful. These messages can fill the kernel log buffer pretty quickly on a busy internet-facing host.

Comment: Seems like we were being attacked by Slowloris - now I class this error message as a good indication of attack (http://ha.ckers.org/slowloris/).